# utf8, utf8BOM, utf8NoBOM Powershell encoding

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, powershell, encoding

I have a couple of powershell automation scripts I wrote that sometimes require editing files used by linux OS family.

I know that windows ends strings in files using the `CR` `LF` flags, while linux uses only the `LF` flag.
Both also use different versions of `utf8` encoding.
While windows is able to read  linux-written files, the opposite is not the same, and this actually causes problems when reading windows-written files in linux.

Yet it seems there's more to it: I discovered windows uses `utf8BOM`, and actually does not fully support natively the simple `utf8` encoding compared to linux.

**My question is this:** When using the `set-content` cmdlet, the default encoding used by powershell is `utf8NoBOM`. What is the actual difference between `utf8`, `utf8BOM` and `utf8NoBOM` when using the `-Encoding` parameter when writing to files?

[From Microsoft's Set-Content manual page:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7)

> **-Encoding**
>
> Specifies the type of encoding for the target file. The default value
> is `utf8NoBOM`.
>
> - utf8: Encodes in UTF-8 format.
> - utf8BOM: Encodes in UTF-8 format with Byte Order Mark (BOM)
> - utf8NoBOM: Encodes in UTF-8 format without Byte Order Mark (BOM)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Powershell specific thing. It is an industry format specification. So, just search the web for each encoding individually to get the details.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Such discussions are had for example:

> MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs
> https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/4021
>
> What's the difference between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom